Getting java.sql.SQLException from DB but it is not execution catch block created for it However it is executing the catch created for Exception
I am trying to insert a record in DB and in one scenario it is throwing

java.sql.SQLException(### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "Schema"."table"."column" (actual: 53, maximum: 50))

but, if I create a catch block to handle it, then the code is not executing through that when exception is raised.
I tried adding catch blocks for java.sql.SQLException and java.lang.Exception and  when the code is throwing java.SQL.SQLException, it is executing from java.lang.Exception catch block, and not java.sql.SQLException block.

Please [edit] your post and add the relevant code, errors, and expected output vs actual output.

Hi @Seenukarthi, Ok .I will.

Hi @Seenukarthi, Ok .I will. Meanwhile can we publish this post, so that if it can have some answers to my problem. I cannot share the current code due to some constraints, however i can provide clarifications to the queries/questions that someone asks in response to my issue.

@VishalGandotra If you could share a small demo project that reproduces the same problem on your GitHub repo, I would look into it. Here are some templates and examples. You can use different table/column/class/etc. names, but it has to reproduce the same error, basically.
